# nmap - Difference between "Filtered" and "Admin-Prohibited"

Tags: nmap, network-scanners

I am a rather new user to nmap. By using some Google-Fu, I am still not able to ascertain what is the criteria used in order to distinguish "filtered" ports from "admin-prohibited" as they both seem related to firewall or network restrictions in general.

As I understand (but maybe I'm wrong), the "filtered" word is used when a port is behind a firewall, for example:

```
Nmap scan report for 10.0.0.2
Host is up, received user-set (0.026s latency).
All 500 scanned ports on 10.69.72.3 are filtered because of 438 no-responses and 62 admin-prohibiteds
```

In this case, nmap has been launched with the `-Pn` parameter in order to perform a host discovery, so that's the reason for the "user-set" and the relative filtered ports.

But I don't get why (and especially **how**) are those 62 admin-prohibited ports shown, so are they the same thing as "filtered"?

Comment: My top hit for the search: https://www.redhat.com/archives/rhl-list/2004-July/msg00204.html

Comment: Thanks schroeder, I found that too, but I didn't understand completely why it was that. I didn't know of the existence of an ICMP "admin prohibited" packet. gowenfawr's answer made me understand that little bit more :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Filtered" means "I sent something, I never got a response, it just disappeared, so I'm guessing that something is filtering the packets out and quietly dropping them."

"Admin Prohibited" means "I sent something, and I got back an ICMP '[Admin Prohibited](http://techgenix.com/understanding-icmp-protocol-part2/)' packet, which clearly indicates that I'm being actively blocked."

Answer (score 2):

Nmap port scan output shows (at least) 2 different things for each port: the **state** of the port, and the **reason** why Nmap decided on that state. In your output, all the ports in the *filtered state* are being presented together, with counts for each of the two *reasons* it decided on that state for each port.

### Port States

A port is really just an address, and at the most basic level there are two states the port can be in: **open** and **closed**. An *open port* means that a process is *listening* and will open a connection with someone who sends a packet to that address. A *closed port* means that there is no process listening, and the operating system will reject a connection to that address explicitly.

There is one more state, though, and that is what your question is about: the **filtered** state. This is less about the state of the port, and more about Nmap's internal state: it simply can't know whether something is listening because *something else* is interfering with or *filtering* the connection attempts. There may or may not be a process listening on that port, but either way, *your scanner* is not being allowed to find out.

### Reasons

When a TCP port is open, there is pretty much only one reason Nmap reports: `syn-ack`. Similarly, when closed it is `reset`. There are a few exceptions for other scan types (TCP Connect may be implemented differently on different systems, resulting in `conn-refused`, for instance). But for the "filtered" state, the reason depends on what the filtering system (most frequently a firewall) does when it receives one of Nmap's probes. Most firewalls will respond in one of two ways: dropping the incoming connection without responding at all, or sending a ICMP Administratively Prohibited message. These are the two reasons that your output shows: dropped connections are `no-response`, and the other are `admin-prohibited`.