# Can anyone tell me at this platform that what is the difference between filtered ports and blocked ports?

Tags: ports

please help me out, I am confused in this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [nmap - Difference between "Filtered" and "Admin-Prohibited"](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/202740/nmap-difference-between-filtered-and-admin-prohibited), [NMAP - Closed vs Filtered](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/182504/nmap-closed-vs-filtered).

Comment: Do you mean in nmap? I googled your title and got a ton of hits, including from the map documentation itself.

Comment: no sir, I dont mean nmap, I'm just asking the difference